# VSCode C/C++ extention run debbuger lldb with command process launch -i filename

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, lldb

Is it possible in VSCode to force launch lldb debugger with command: process launch -i filename?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on how to set up the debugger is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_debugging-your-code

To make lldb launch a file, you need to have a `launch.json` configured and include this line:

`"program": "${workspaceFolder}/whatever-your-compiled-filename-is"`

I also found this guide helpful for getting started: https://medium.com/@piyushchauhan/debugging-c-and-c-with-vscode-77dae50eaf7f

Comment: I'm able to start debugging with lldb and vs code, but point is I'cant pass parameter -i filename to redirect input stream